# How does Magento Connect use author information in packaged extensions

Tags: magento-connect, extensions

When packaging an extension for Magento Connect you are prompted to include author information.

While I realize the first author must match the credentials from the Magento Connect account used to submit the extension, I am not sure:

1. How the information is used
2. How multiple author information is used

One concern is that the email address is made public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first user field, MUST be the same as the username of your “[magentocommerce.com](http://magento.com/)” account. This account will be displayed in your Extension author section in Magento Connect. All the details of members contributed in the extensions can be added further.

Comment: So, you are saying the authors are viewable from within the Magento Connect account? This would mean additional author information is used for the purpose of the extension author to track contributors? If so, please add to your answer and I'll accept. This actually would answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Magento Connect used these information to specify the author properties (only the first author!). Only the account with these email address can interact with the extension (e.g. update or edit, comment reviews, ...). The email address are not visible for community users.

Comment: What I assumed, but why enable additional authors if the information is not used?

Comment: According to my research and a discussion on Twitter, the entries have technical reasons. The authorship is identified with it. The first entry must be specified, all others are optional.

Comment: I think, only Magento can answer how the information is used (internally).

Comment: Hello again, below the answer of Magento (from a Product Manager): [...] the author is only for collecting data. Nothing more.

Comment: Once again, this does not answer why additional author information is available, or how it is used. I assume the first author is used to validate the account (as you suggested), but this does not answer why additional author information is available, or how it is used.